# Telnet Client connection refused - JAVA

Tags: java, telnet

I'm trying create a telnet client(apache) connection to global IP address.

If I use something like below,I  can could establish the connection.

```
private TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();

telnet.connect("172.xx.xxx.xx", port);
```

However  writing it something like below,I  get "connection refused error".

```
private TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();

String host = "172.xx.xxx.xx";

telnet.connect(host, port);
```

Any suggestion?(i could not find same error in forums, also I am  new at asking questions :) )

Comment: Does what you're trying to connect to accept telnet connections?

Comment: is your port the same ? when you rewrote the code ?

Comment: yes same port. this code for send some command/ get response to servers. this code is next to after create a connection. when i use "telnet.connect("172.xx.xxx.xx", port);" all works fine:/. out = new PrintWriter(telnet.getOutputStream(), true);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      telnet.getInputStream()));

Comment: post full code, somewhere you got typo, Or maybe you use "connect(host, port)" on another environment/system?

Answer (score 0):

here is my full code;

```
public void connectionCreater(String host, int port,String uID,String pass,
                String account, String password) {  
            try {
                //telnet.connect("172.xx.xxx.xx", port); this is works. 
                telnet.connect(host, port);
                out = new PrintWriter(telnet.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        telnet.getInputStream()));
                if (readUntilThenExecute("login: ", uID + "\r")) {
                    if (readUntilThenExecute("Password: ", pass + "\r")) {
                        if (readUntilThenExecute("Enter User Name", account)) {
                            if (readUntilThenExecute("Enter Password", password)) {
                //to do stuff           }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                out.close();
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException y) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean readUntilThenExecute(String word, String command) {
            try {
                String result1 = "";
                char[] incoming = new char[2048];
                boolean check = true;
                while (check) {
                    int lenght = in.read(incoming);
                    result1 = String.copyValueOf(incoming, 0, lenght);
                    System.out.println(result1);
                    if (result1.contains(word)) {
                        out.println(command);
                        check = false;
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: thanks for attention i solve the problem. my colleague changes db host records, i just see in debug...thx

Answer (score 0):

1.Install telnet use this command in terminal(Applications/Accessories/Terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd telnetd
```

---

2.Edit /etc/inetd.conf using your favourite file editor with root permission,add this line:

```
telnet stream tcp nowait telnetd /usr/sbin/tcpd /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
```

---

3.Edit /etc/xinetd.conf,make its content look like following:

```
# Simple configuration file for xinetd
#
# Some defaults, and include /etc/xinetd.d/
defaults
{
# Please note that you need a log_type line to be able to use log_on_success
# and log_on_failure. The default is the following :
# log_type = SYSLOG daemon info
instances = 60
log_type = SYSLOG authpriv
log_on_success = HOST PID
log_on_failure = HOST
cps = 25 30
}
```

---

4.You can change telnet port number by edit /etc/services with this line:

```
telnet        23/tcp
```

---

5.If you’re not satisfied with default configuration.Edit `etc/xinetd.d/telnet`, add following:

```
# default: on
# description: The telnet server serves telnet sessions; it uses
# unencrypted username/password pairs for authentication.
service telnet
{
disable = no
flags = REUSE
socket_type = stream
wait = no
user = root
server = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
log_on_failure += USERID
}
```

---

add these lines as you like:

```
only_from = 192.168.120.0/24 #Only users in 192.168.120.0 can access to
only_from = .bob.com #allow access from bob.com
no_access = 192.168.120.{101,105} #not allow access from the two IP.
access_times = 8:00-9:00 20:00-21:00 #allow access in the two times
......
```

---

6.Use this command to start telnet server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd start
```